# Absolute value inequalities with integrals

Tags: integration, inequality

I don't understand why the following makes sense. Here, $1\leq t \leq 2$:

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_1^2\Big|\int^t_1 f(x)x^2 \ dx \Big|\ dt &\leq \int_1^2 \int_1^t \Big|f(x)x^2\Big| \ dxdt\\
> &\leq \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \Big| f(x)x^2\Big| \ dxdt\\
> &\leq \int_1^2 \int_1^2 M \ dxdt, \quad \text{where } M = \max_{1\leq x\leq2}\Big|f(x)x^2\Big|
> \end{align}
> $$

I don't understand either of these three inequality steps, especially why the inequality holds when $t$ is replaced with two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first inequality follows from
$$\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|\leq \int_a^b|f(x)|dx.$$
The second inequality follows from: if $f(x)\geq 0$ in $[a,b]$, then for any subinterval $[a,c]\subset[a,b]$, we have
$$\int_a^cf(x)dx\leq \int_a^bf(x)dx.$$
The third inequality follows from:
if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ in $[a,b]$, then
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\leq \int_a^bg(x)dx.$$